Convert to int if not None, else keep None
I have a request dict and I need to parse some elements into either int or None. This works:
request = {"a": "123", "c": "456"}
a, b = request.get("a"), request.get("b")                       # too many 
a, b = int(a) if a is not None else None, int(b) if b is not None else None             # repetitions of "a" and "b" in this code!
print(a, b)  # 123 None

but I guess it might be simplified, ideally with a one-liner.
Is there a workaround, with standard built-in functions (and no extra helper util function) to be able to do a = int(request.get("a")) without int producing an error if the input is None?
Note: in this question I'm not really interested in the for loop part, what I'm interested in is how to simplify this:
a = request.get("a")
a = int(a) if a is not None else None

which I don't find pythonic.
Is there a way to simplify this pattern:
... if a is not None else None
?

I would use a try-except.

@user459872 Yes but then my solution is shorter, I wanted to know if there is even shorter, possibly a one-liner.

a, b = (a and int(a) for a in map(request.get, "ab")) --- would that answer your needs?

Your code is buggy, it will produce None if the input is 0.

@tripleee Presumably it would be "0" then, in which case it'd work fine.

@tripleee you're right! fixed!

@trincot if the variables are "foo", "bar", it doesn't work.

Of course it wouldn't. So what are the names of your keys?

@trincot it can be any string

Alter it slightly to ('foo', 'bar') instead of 'ab'?!

Something like a, b = ((res := request.get(k)) and int(res) for k in ('a', 'b')) maybe?

@deceze how would you simplify this code? (or would you keep it as it is?)

After your question update and comment, a, b = (None if a is None else int(a) for a in map(request.get, ("foo", "bar")))

@deceze yes sure, the for loop isn't a problem. What I'm interested in is how to simplify a = request.get("a"); a = int(a) if a is not None else None

I'd write a helper function. Not everything needs to be done in a one-liner.

The best simplification here is a and int(a), assuming your values will always be non-empty strings. But anything that needs this sort of asterisk is probably better off being a helper function.

code golf could be a better fit for this question.

@Basj One-liners can be convenient but they can also be rather esoteric. If you're a professional developer you need to think about the possibility of someone else needing to maintain your code. Don't make it difficult just for the sake of brevity. See: Zen of Python

@SIGHUP Yes exactly, I only use one-liners if they are well explicit, easy to understand, and "zen of python compatible". If not, I prefer multiple lines. Here I was just curious if there is a nice solution with or or and or something else to avoid the not-very-beautiful a = int(a) if a is not None else None.


ideally with a one-liner

Avoid one-liners. Learn how a beautiful code looks like in Python. Avoid overusing the word "pythonic".
request = {'a': '123', 'c': '456'}

if 'a' in request:
    a = int(request['a'])
else:
    a = None

if 'b' in request:
    b = int(request['b'])
else:
    b = None


I would make a simple function to encapsulate the logic and indeed avoid code repetition:
def process_request(request, keys):
    for k in keys:
        try:
            yield int(request[k])
        except (TypeError, KeyError):
            yield None

Now, you can do:
request = {"a": "123", "c": "456"}
a, b = process_request(request, ['a','b'])
print(a, b)

Output:
123 None

You can achieve this without custom function using exec. But I wouldn't suggest this route as using ecec can lead to security risks. I would use a helper function, I don;t know why the OP is against that, it is the smart choice here.
However, here is a solution using exec:
request = {"a": "123", "c": "456"}
keys = ['a','b']
for k in keys:
    try:
        exec(f"{k} = int(request[k])") #assuming you want to get the variable name from the keys
    except (TypeError, KeyError):
        exec(f"{k} = None")

The point is using try/except in the loop.
try:
    a = int(request.get("a"))
except:
    a = None


Thanks, but as a said in the question, with no extra helper function.

@Basj I have added function-free options

I think you could use:
a = int(request.get("a")) if "a" in request.
The same thing for b variable
